# Cannot get connectionId responsible for update in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose v3.8.7 with mongoDB v2.6.1. The code I have written uses mongoDB connection pooling with 100 connections. I am using the following piece of code to update a collection:

```
model.update( findquery, updatequery, { upsert: true }, function(err, numberAffected, rawResponse) {
...
});
```

The returned rawResponse looks like this:

```
{ ok: true, n: 1, updatedExisting: true }
```

The above response doesn't include connectionId. How will I be able to get connection Id responsible for update in my code?

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do that you need the ID of the connection there?

Comment: I am using the same connection pool for multiple dbs. Concurrently requests will go to multiple dbs. I want to see how effectively connections are used among the dbs. I have to validate whether any db is holding the connection or not.

Comment: It would be better to use separate a connection pool per DB.

Comment: The number of dbs in my project will increase dynamically. So I wont have control over the connection pool. The number of connections to mongos / mongod will dynamically increase